# Flutter - Why debugger is debuging the code under the function call before function fully debugged?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, vscode-debugger

First of all it is very hard to explain my question for me, so sorry from now for bad explanation.
I was debugging my flutter project and something caught my eye.

```
Widget _loginbutton() {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 35.0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            press();
            if (check == true) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserPage()),
              );
            } else {}
          },
          color: Colors.white70,
          child: Text(
            'Giris Yap',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my login button and

```
void press() async {
    final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "accept": "/"},
        body: json.encode({
          'username': id,
          'password': pwd,
          'deviceId': devid,
        }));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print("OK");
      if (jsonResponse['success'] == true) {
        // globaluserData.setName(jsonResponse['data']['firstName'].toString());
        check = true;
      }
    } else {
      check = false;
      print("NOT OK");
    }
    print(response.body);
  }
```

This is my press function which calling by onPress.

In debug mode, debugger goes to onPressed, then press() function. In press() function, it encodes the json data and before getting the response, it quits from press() function and continues to debug if statement in _loginbutton under press(). It does what it should if check is true then it continues debugging from final response line in press() function and finishes it. My check is false at the beginning and because of that if it becomes true once, then my if statement in _loginbutton works again even I get no 200 status code because if statement in _loginbutton works before check could change. Why debugger does not finish press() function to debug and then continues with rest and how can I solve this. I write in VSCode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I understand, it happens because of async, program does not wait for response to continue. But still don't have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this The reason is, you're calling the async function in a non-async function.

```
Future<bool> press() async {
   final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "accept": "/"},
      body: json.encode({
      'username': id,
      'password': pwd,
      'deviceId': devid,
    }));
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print("OK");
  if (jsonResponse['success'] == true) {
    // globaluserData.setName(jsonResponse['data']['firstName'].toString());
    return true;
   }
  }
  else {
     return false;
     print("NOT OK");
 }
 print(response.body);
 }
```

---

```
Widget _loginbutton() {
   return Container(
    child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 35.0,
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        press().then((value) {
           if(value){
     Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserPage()),
          );}
        }); 
      },
      color: Colors.white70,
      child: Text(
        'Giris Yap',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It is waiting for response now but I could not check if check is true for Navigator.push, could not determine where should I place the if statement. It gives error when I try to place it on top of Navigator.push()

Comment: I forgot to add. I fixed it, you can see.

Comment: Yes, it worked now and i get the logic! Çok sağolasın.